# How about my understanding of my first java lab in the introduction of java programming?Is my code correct or not?

Tags: java

```
// Create a method called displayHighScorePosition
// it should a players name as a parameter, and the 2nd parameter as a position in the high score table
// You should display the player's name along with a message like " managed to get into position " and the
// position they got and a further message " on the high score table".
//
// Create a 2nd method called calculateHighScorePosition
// it should be sent one argument only, the player score
// it should return an in
// the return data should be
// 1 if the score is >=1000
// 2 if the score is >=500 and < 1000
// 3 if the score is >=100 and < 500
// 4 in all other cases
// call both methods and display the results of the following
// a score of 1500, 900, 400 and 50

    public class Challenge {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


      int position=calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
      displayHighScorePosition("Stone",position);
      position=calculateHighScorePosition(900);
      displayHighScorePosition("shawn",position);
      position=calculateHighScorePosition(400);
      displayHighScorePosition("Simon",position);
      position=calculateHighScorePosition(50);
      displayHighScorePosition("sks",position);   }


        public static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName, int position) {
            System.out.println(playerName + " managed to get into position");
            System.out.println(position + " on the high score table");
        }

        public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
           if(playerScore>1000){
               return 1;
           }else if(playerScore>500&&playerScore<1000) {
               return 2;
           }else if(playerScore>100&&playerScore<500) {
               return 3;
           }else {
               return 4;
           }
           }

        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `displayHighScorePosition("stone", calculateHighScorePosition(11));`

Comment: @KevinO Yes but the assignment calls for _a 2nd parameter as a position in the high score table_. I have to assume that value is returned by the function `calculateHighScorePosition()`. So it should probably be `displayHighScorePosition("stone", calculateHighScorePosition(1500));` Not sure where the `11` comes from.

Comment: I make some changes for my mistakes

Comment: int position=calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
  displayHighScorePosition("Stone",position);
  position=calculateHighScorePosition(900);
  displayHighScorePosition("shawn",position);
  position=calculateHighScorePosition(400);
  displayHighScorePosition("Simon",position);
  position=calculateHighScorePosition(50);
  displayHighScorePosition("sks",position);

Comment: Also, the `&&` parts of the `if` statements are not needed.

Comment: I finish edit my question

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this question, as this community is about *helping* you to solve your problem yourself, not about *solving* it *for* you. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After the edits, the basic program seems OK, with the following caveat:

> the return data should be
>     1 if the score is >=1000
>     2 if the score is >=500 and < 1000
>     3 if the score is >=100 and < 500
>     4 in all other cases

But the current tests omit the `=` part of the test. As an example, try running a test case with the score equal to 500. What is the result?

So the checks should probably be like the following, incorporating both the `=` and the note from @JohnyMopp about not needing the parts beyond the `&&`:

```
if(playerScore >= 1000){
       return 1;
} else if (playerScore >= 500) {
       return 2;
} else if (playerScore >= 100) {
       return 3;
} else {
       return 4;
}
```

Writing some test cases at the boundaries is the best way to ensure the program logic functions correctly. So, in addition to the specified results, add some tests at 1000, 500, 100, 499, 99. Basically, start to think of the corner cases that can affect the outcome.

Some stdout examples here: https://ideone.com/sGi48C